# Compare short dates in ubuntu with date other virtual server in bash script

Tags: bash, date

I have a command to get date of creation of virtual server, get information from line
`Created:        Mon Mar 28 07:19:50 UTC 2022 (3 weeks ago)`:

```
root@hcloud-admin:/home/scripts# hcloud server describe Miguel-Zabbix-hel1-dc2 | awk 'NR == 4' | awk -F " " '{ print $2, $3, $4 }'
```

Output:

```
Mon Mar 28
```

And also have date from my mine server host with `hcloud` CLI:

```
root@hcloud-admin:/home/scripts# date +"%a %b %d"
Fri Apr 22
```

Could you please help, Is this possible to compare this both of date using `bash script`, that to find out if it's been 10 days or not, after server was created?

If 10 days is passed, I want to use command `hcloud server poweroof  Miguel-Zabbix-hel1-dc2` in bash script.

Full output:

```
root@hcloud-admin:/home/scripts# hcloud server describe Miguel-Zabbix-hel1-dc2
ID:             191220000
Name:           Miguel-Zabbix-hel1-dc2
Status:         running
Created:        Mon Mar 28 07:19:50 UTC 2022 (3 weeks ago)
Server Type:    cpx11 (ID: 22)
  ID:           22
  Name:         cpx11
  Description:  CPX 11
  Cores:        2
  Memory:       2 GB
  Disk:         40 GB
  Storage Type: local
Public Net:
  IPv4:
    IP:         11.111.111.111
    Blocked:    no
    DNS:        static.111.111.111.111.clients.your-server.de
  IPv6:
    IP:         0a99:4f9:p099:0d0b::/555
    Blocked:    no
  Floating IPs:
    No Floating IPs
Private Net:
    No Private Networks
Volumes:
  No Volumes
Image:
  ID:           15512600
  Type:         system
  Status:       available
  Name:         ubuntu-20.04
  Description:  Ubuntu 20.04
  Image size:   -
  Disk size:    5 GB
  Created:      Thu Apr 23 17:55:14 UTC 2020 (2 years ago)
  OS flavor:    ubuntu
  OS version:   20.04
  Rapid deploy: yes
Datacenter:
  ID:           3
  Name:         hel1-dc2
  Description:  Helsinki 1 DC 2
  Location:
    Name:               hel1
    Description:        Helsinki DC Park 1
    Country:            FI
    City:               Helsinki
    Latitude:           60.169855
    Longitude:          24.938379
Traffic:
  Outgoing:     208 MB
  Ingoing:      280 MB
  Included:     22 TB
Backup Window:  Backups disabled
Rescue System:  disabled
ISO:
  No ISO attached
Protection:
  Delete:       no
  Rebuild:      no
Labels:
  Name: Zabbix
```

Comment: What's the full output of hcloud? Having the year would be helpful.

Comment: @choroba I added full output

Comment: What does it say instead of `3 weeks ago` when the file is 10 days old?

Comment: @choroba Just 1 week

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is possible. The trick is to convert both date/time strings into "the number of seconds since the epoch" format (date +%s) and then compare the result. On modern versions of Linux, the 'date' command can interpret just about any reasonably formatted date string and convert it to various formats:

```
date_1=$(hcloud server describe Miguel-Zabbix-hel1-dc2 | sed -n 's/^Created:\([^(]*\).*$/\1/p')
seconds_1=$(date -s "${date_1}" +%s)
seconds_2=$(date +%s)
day_diff=$(((seconds_2 - seconds_1)/86400)) # Number of seconds in a day = 86,400.
```

Note that the $((...)) construct only does integer arithmetic, and it rounds down, so you may want to adjust the arithmetic to suit your exact needs.  Also, this simple calculation does not take account of any of the date calculation nuances, like daylight savings, or leap-seconds, etc. But for your situation, I doubt these are very important.

Also, note that I used `sed` instead of `awk`. `sed` is more concise for this type of job, but can be a bit complex, so I'll break down the  `-n 's/^Created:\([^(]*\).*$/\1/p'` parameters for you:

- `-n`         : Do not print each line by default.
- `s/pat/rep/p`: If `pat` is found in the current line, replace with `rep` and print.

In our case, `pat` is:

- `^Created:`  : Beginning of line (^), followed by the exact string 'Created:',
- `\(`         : start remembering what follows,
- `[^(]*`      : any character ([...]) that is not (^) in the string '(', repeated 0 or more times (*),
- `\)`         : stop remembering,
- `.*$`        : any single character (.) repeated 0 or more times, followed by the end of the line ($).

And `rep` is

- `\1`         : The first thing remembered (i.e. everything after `Created:`    and before `(`).

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you very much. I just add symbol `$` to `day_diff=$((($seconds_2 - $seconds_1)/86400))`

Comment: The dollar sign is implied inside ((...)), but there is no harm including it for clarity. It is also a good habit to always enclose variable names in {...}. There are times when omitting this will cause bugs, so getting in the habit now will help you to avoid those situations: `day_diff=$(((${seconds_2} - ${seconds_1})/86400))`. This is a style preference, not a requirement.